How to implement a bottom-to-top scrolling text animation using Kotlin in Android?
I've successfully implemented left-to-right animation, but I'm facing issues with implementing a Vertical animation.
In Android there is a inbuild function for horizonatal scrolling which is
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:padding="10dp"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"

But I have to do from low to up. Like this below ex:

Does anyone have ideas on how to achieve this? I've come across several suggestions, but none of them have worked so far.
**
one of the attempt i'm sharing through using AI.**
package com.brainintelcorp.brainintel

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView

class VerticalMarqueeTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        isSingleLine = true
        setHorizontallyScrolling(true)
        startMarquee()
    }

    private fun startMarquee() {
        val translateAnimation = TranslateAnimation(
            0f, 0f, height.toFloat(), -height.toFloat()
        ).apply {
            duration = 10000 // Set your desired speed
            repeatCount = TranslateAnimation.INFINITE
        }
        startAnimation(translateAnimation)
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()
        clearAnimation()
    }
}

now we have to change in xml also.
<com.brainintelcorp.brainintel.VerticalMarqueeTextView
    android:id="@+id/tvQuestionContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="14sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/question_content"
    android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageLogo" />

I have changed the xml for the vertical animation. But i have no idea how can i start the animation as a basic knowledge on kotlin.
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tvQuestionContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="14sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:ellipsize="none"  
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/question_content"
    android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageLogo" />

I've tried making changes in the activity using AI suggestions, but they didn't work. Does anyone have ideas on how to achieve this?
